# Split One Cell With Linebreaks But grab 2 Rows At A Time Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of places in one cell, and a list of coordinates in the other, so one line of my places corresponds to 2 lines of my coordinates, so there is a mismatch. I need to:

1. Put the locations into one cell and use a pipe "|" to separate them so they can be imported, for that I have used this:

   =SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"|")
2. I need to grab TWO rows of my coordinates (latitude and longitude) so this then corresponds to my location. I cannot figure out how to do this bit as need two rows, rather than one.

Some locations have empty coordinates also. [image: RAW DATA]

[image: Desired Outcome]

Comment: Google Sheets, preferably.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you need? Try this:

`={SUBSTITUTE($A$1,CHAR(10),"|");regexreplace(clean(trim(REGEXREPLACE($B$1,"new_long.*;",""))),";\ ",";\|");regexreplace(clean(trim(REGEXREPLACE($B$1,"new_lat.*;",""))),";\ ",";\|")}`

or this:

`={SUBSTITUTE($A$1,CHAR(10),"|"),regexreplace(clean(trim(REGEXREPLACE($B$1,"new_long.*;",""))),";\ ",";\|"),regexreplace(clean(trim(REGEXREPLACE($B$1,"new_lat.*;",""))),";\ ",";\|")}`